# compiling musescore for uCLinux with QT and cmake

Tags: qt, path, compilation, cmake, uclinux

I've try few things but I still have this error when trying to cmake for blackfin:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:116 (message):

  Fatal error: QT (version >= 4.5.0) required.  Cmake tries to detect QT4 by

  searching for 'qmake' in your PATH.If you have QT4 installed, make sure

  qmake is found in your PATH.  If you compiled QT4 yourself make sure your

  new qmake ist found _first_ in your PATH.
```

I'm trying to compile the source of musescore 0.9.5 to keep it compatible with the existing version of QT in uClinux options

What I did is to compile the uClinux kernel with QT lib so I can have the suitable embedded QT.

then I modified the Makefile of musescore to build with uclinux compilers. I've try different things so I show here the latest trial:

```
bfin:

        mkdir build;

        mkdir install;                               \

        cd build;

        cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=bfin.cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=TRUE -\

DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLin\

ux/rev2011R1/uclinux-dist/lib/qt-embedded/build-qt-embedded-linux-opensource-sr\

c-4.5.1/bin         -libdir=/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/cod\

e/uCLinux/rev2011R1/uclinux-dist/lib/qt-embedded/build-qt-embedded-linux-openso\

urce-src-4.5.1/lib    \
                -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${PREFIX}" \
                mscore;
```

in the CMakeLists.txt I did add:

```
link_directories(/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLinux/r\

ev2011R1/uclinux-dist/lib/qt-embedded/build-qt-embedded-linux-opensource-src-4.\

5.1/bin)



SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLi\

nux/rev2011R1/uclinux-dist/lib/qt-embedded/build-qt-embedded-linux-opensource-s\

rc-4.5.1/bin)



SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLi\

nux/rev2011R1/uclinux-dist/lib/qt-embedded/build-qt-embedded-linux-opensource-s\

rc-4.5.1/bin)



SET(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE /home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uC\

Linux/rev2011R1/uclinux-dist/lib/qt-embedded/build-qt-embedded-linux-opensource\

-src-4.5.1/bin)
```

my bfin.cmake look like that:

```
# this one is important                                                     

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
#this one not so much                                                       

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)


#                                                                           

SET (BFIN "/opt/uClinux/bfin-uclinux")


# specify the cross compiler                                                
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    ${BFIN}/bin/bfin-uclinux-gcc)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER   ${BFIN}/bin/bfin-uclinux-g++)
SET(CMAKE_LINKER        ${BFIN}/bin/bfin-uclinux-ld)


#/opt/uClinux/bfin-uclinux/bfin-uclinux/runtime/usr/lib                     

LINK_DIRECTORIES("${BFIN}/usr/lib")



SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH

  /opt/uClinux/bfin-uclinux/bfin-uclinux

  /opt/uClinux/bfin-linux-uclibc

  /opt/uClinux/bfin-linux-uclibc/bfin-linux-uclibc/runtime)


# search for programs in the build host directories                         

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories                       

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Thanks in advance for the help,

William

Answer (score 0):

You need to put qmake in your $PATH. If you prefer to use QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE it has to point to the actual qmake binary and not the directory.

That being said, MuseScore 0.9.5 is a very very old version of MuseScore, the current version is 1.1 and 1.2 is coming soon. Check http://musescore.org for more information about MuseScore and don't hesitate to contact the developers on #musescore on freenode.net or on the developer mailing list at http://musescore.org/mailing-list

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mentioned I did add in my .bashrc the path already. Note that I'm speaking about cross compiling to blackfin uCLinux here not Linux x86. anyway, it should work the same. for muse core, on my PC yes I use the latest but over the 0.9.5 they are using qt 4.6 which is not yet supported by blackfin uCLinux. Thus I had to downgrade to try to make it work. Note that QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE with qmake binary doesn't work either, I tried it before.